# cannot use variable to access array member inside field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mean

why can I not use a variable to access something inside my document? if I hard code the field it works but using a variable it does not.

```
building = "AS"
room = "243"
item = "whiteBoard.votes[0]"

RI.findOne({$and: [{"building": building }, {"room": room}]}, (err, x) => {
    console.log(x.whiteBoard.votes[0]) //works
    console.log(x[item]) //undefined
```

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @BeingSunny that isn't really applicable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality isn't defined anywhere- so it isn't expected to work.  You have to split the accesses:

```
console.log(x["whiteBoard"]["votes"][0])
```

Alternatively if you need to be able to access keys using the `X.Y` notation, you can split the string on the `.` and access these individually.

Another option would be to use `lodash`'s `get` method: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get